# PHP get results from mysql DB with href links and label

Tags: php, mysql, href

I am trying to get the proper syntax to pull a url and an associated label from a mysql database and put them into an href.  I am just not getting the syntax correct.

The code below gets the link but not the label that goes with it.  "$title" does not display the label.

```
 <?php
        $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "showcase", "showcase123", "nasja723_Showcase");
        // Check connection
        if ($conn-> connect_error) {
         die ("Connection failed:". $conn-> connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "Select Title, Fname, Lname,url from Showcase";
        $result = $conn-> query($sql);
        if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
            While ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc())  {
                echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>",'<a href=' . $row['url'] . '>$title </a>',"</td>";  


            }
            Echo "</table>";
        }
        else {
            echo "0 result";
        }


$conn-> close();

?>
```

Comment: Look at the value you're getting from the DB that works - `$row['url']`. Compare it to the one that does not - `$title`.

Comment: where is **$title** defined or did you mean **$row['Title']** instead ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
echo "<td>",'<a href=' . $row['url'] . '>'.$row['Title'].' </a>',"</td>";
```

`$title` doesn't actually exist, you need to access the 'Title' column returned in the row and if it did, it wouldn't be displayed in single quotes, you would have to use double quotes or concatenate it.